# Pass 2 variables from browser based form to PowerShell to create and name a folder?

Tags: windows

First off, I am a serious newbie so please be gentle.

I am going to try and build a small browser based form (just pure HTML hopefully) to create standardized project numbers.  This will require two variables, one for the facility and one for the project title.

I found a PowerShell script that will create the folders I need, but I do not understand how to make the form send things to it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I assume you're trying to do this to make a central location for different people to do it...  But why not just use that PowerShell script and modify it to accept the input from the user?  Then they would just double-click it, respond to the prompts, and it's done.

Comment: Oh, I never thought of that!  Yes multiple people (about 10) would need to do this.